# how to aggregate data by month overlapping postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, scd2

I have SCD table type 2 that I join with various other tables and I am looking to aggregate sum total from any entity that was active (by active I mean the ones that don't yet have an end_date) during an individual month.

currently, I have a query similar to this (let's say aggregating data for the month of May 2022 and April 2022):

```
select
        count(1) as enitities_agg,
        DATE_TRUNC('Month', h.start) as date,
        sum(h.price) filter (where c.name='HIGH') as sum_total,
        ----....----

    from 
        project as p
        join class as c on p.class_id = c.id
        join stage as s on s.project_id = p.id
        join stage_info as si on si.stage_id = s.id 
        join history as h on h.stage_info_id = si.id 
        
    where 
        h.start <= '2022-06-01' and
        h.end_date >= '2022-04-01' and
        COALESCE(p.end_date, '2099-01-01') >= '2022-04-01' and
        COALESCE(p.start_date, '2099-01-01') <= '2022-06-01' and
        COALESCE(stage.end, '2099-01-01') >= '2022-04-01' and
        h.price is not null and
        h.price != 0 
            
    group by DATE_TRUNC('Month', h.start)
```

It aggregates fine only those whose history **starts** in May or April, not the ones that overlap those months and are still active.

The problem I have is that some history entities start in April, March, etc., and still haven't ended by May. Because I group with `group by DATE_TRUNC('Month', h.start)` i.e. by history start date, I don't get the entities that start earlier than April or May and continue to be active after May, I get aggregates only in those months that they have started in.

I was trying to do it by generating series and group by the generated month, however, I didn't find a way that would group them correctly. Example, of one experimentation that I tried.

```
 from 
        generate_series('2022-03-01', '2022-07-01', INTERVAL '1 month') as mt
        join project as p on    COALESCE(p.end_date, '2099-01-01') >= mt and
                                COALESCE(p.start_date, '2099-01-01') <= mt + INTERVAL '1 month'
    
        join class as c on p.class_id = c.id
        join stage as stage on  stage.project_id = p.id and 
                                        COALESCE(stage.end, '2099-01-01') >= mt
        join stage_info as si on si.stage_id = stage.id 
        join history as h on h.stage_info_id = si.id 
        
    where 
        h.start <= mt and
        h.end_date >= mt + INTERVAL '1 month' and
        h.price is not null and
        h.price != 0 
            
    group by mt
```

How would it be possible to iterate through the history table aggregating any active entities in a month and group them by the same month and get something like this?

```
"enitities_agg" |  "date"                 |   "sum_total"
832             |  "2022-04-01 00:00:00"  |   15432234
1020            |  "2022-05-01 00:00:00"  |   19979458
```

Comment: 1. remove grouping, check the detail result first to see how it fits your expectation, 2. there's `sum(entity.price)` in first example, but we cannot guess its role in query because entity table is not present.

Comment: my bad, entity.price, should have been h.price. 
Could you elaborate on the first point a bit more? With removed grouping, I get an aggregate of all which to my calculations seems correct and I can't think of a way to get a correct aggregate that would incorporate overlapping dates as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your logic is: if any day of begin_ - _end interval falls into month, count it in. This was the hardest part to guess from the desired results.

So I guess you need this:

```
with dim as (
  select
  m::date as month_start
  ,(date_trunc('month', m) + interval '1 month - 1 day')::date as month_end
  ,to_char(date_trunc('month', m), 'Mon') as month
  from generate_series('2022-01-01', '2022-08-01', INTERVAL '1 month') as m
)
SELECT
dim.month
, sum(coalesce(t.price, 0)) as sum_price
FROM dim
left join test as t
on t.begin_ <= dim.month_end
and t._end >= dim.month_start
group by dim.month_start, dim.month
order by dim.month_start, dim.month
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=614030d4db5e03876f693a9a8a5ff122

Answer (score 1):

You want all history entities was happened during 2022-May? If so, the following maybe help.

```
daterange(h.start,
    h.end_date,
    '[]') && daterange('2022-05-01', '2022-06-01', '[]');
```

---

demo:

```
CREATE temp TABLE test (
    begin_ date,
    _end date
);

INSERT INTO test
    VALUES ('2022-01-01', '2022-05-01');

INSERT INTO test
    VALUES ('2022-01-01', '2022-05-11');

INSERT INTO test
    VALUES ('2022-05-01', '2022-07-11');

INSERT INTO test
    VALUES ('2022-06-11', '2022-07-11');

SELECT
    *,
    daterange(begin_, _end, '[]')
FROM
    test t
WHERE
    daterange(t.begin_, t._end, '[]') && daterange('2022-05-01', '2022-05-31', '[]');
```

---

**&&** range operator reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE

Comment: What does '[]' part stand for as a third argument in daterange() function? Is it the same as in maths, [] as inclusive and () as exclusive?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the daterange function was really helpful as I have never encountered it before and I need to work a lot with date ranges at the moment. 

However, I might have formatted the question quite misleadingly in the beginning. This answer is perfect for getting an aggregate for a single month, however, I am struggling to expand it to get the correct aggregate values for multiple months at a time. See updated question.

Comment: @SimonasPetkevičius you are right. [ is inclusive, ( is exclusive.

Comment: @SimonasPetkevičius I am a little bit of lost. can you share the sample data in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14 and also share the intended result.

Comment: sorry for not being that clear. Here is the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=699f4828871746a8dc7fe01d13d538c7
the desired outcome is at the bottom. as you can see I want months from the given date range and the total sum of the price for each month of the period.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f8d8187e083c886e687a4232706764f4 the best I came. since july aug, both are null. I don't know how to deal with that... @SimonasPetkevičius